# Regex: how do I match a character before other capture characters?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match on a list of strings where I want to make sure the first character is not the equals sign, don't capture that match. So, for a list (excerpted from pip freeze) like:

```
ply==3.10
powerline-status===2.6.dev9999-git.b-e52754d5c5c6a82238b43a5687a5c4c647c9ebc1-
psutil==4.0.0
ptyprocess==0.5.1
```

I want the captured output to look like this:

```
==3.10
==4.0.0
==0.5.1
```

I first thought using a negative lookahead `(?![^=])` would work, but with a regular expression of `(?![^=])==[0-9]+.*` it ends up capturing the line I don't want:

```
==3.10
==2.6.dev9999-git.b-e52754d5c5c6a82238b43a5687a5c4c647c9ebc1-
==4.0.0
==0.5.1
```

I also tried using a non-capturing group `(?:[^=])` with a regex of `(?:[^=])==[0-9]+.*` but that ends up capturing the first character which I also don't want:

```
y==3.10
l==4.0.0
s==0.5.1
```

So the question is this: How can one match but not capture a string before the rest of the regex?

Comment: You can't get this exact behavior without a lookaround.  The alternative would be to use `(?:[^=])(==[0-9]+.*)` and then replace with the first capture group.  Your tool probably supports this.

Comment: Use `\b==[0-9.]+`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my tool (sublime text) also supports lookbehind, see my answer or grail's

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep, your word boundary solution also works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Negative look behind would be the go:

```
(?<!=)==[0-9.]+
```

Also, here is the site I like to use:

http://www.rubular.com/

Of course it does some times help if you advise which engine/software you are using so we know what limitations there might be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the version numbers from the text you could capture not an equals sign `([^=])` in the first capturing group followed by matching `==` and the version numbers`\d+(?:\.\d+)+`. Then in the replacement you would use your capturing group.

**Regex**

[`([^=])==\d+(?:\.\d+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/OqJDOI/1/)

**Replacement**

Group 1 `$1`

**Note**

You could also use `==[0-9]+.*` or `==[0-9.]+` to match the double equals signs and version numbers but that would be a very broad match. The first would also match `====1test` and the latter would also match `==..`

Comment: I should've explained the context better - I wanted to match with the version numbers with the equal signs within a text editor then delete them. Because of this I didn't want to do any multi-step programmatic solutions.

Answer (score -1):

There's another regex operator called a 'lookbehind assertion' (also called positive lookbehind) `?<=` - and in my above example using it in the expression `(?<=[^=])==[0-9]+.*` results in the expected output:

```
==3.10
==4.0.0
==0.5.1
```

At the time of this writing, it took me a while to discover this - notably the lookbehind assertion currently isn't supported in the popular regex tool regexr.

If there's alternatives to using lookbehind to solve I'd love to hear it.

[image]

Comment: This is an  edit, not an answer. Also, note that it's JS implementation of regex that doesn't support lookbehind.